# Spring JMS: Disable DLQ for ActiveMQ from client

Tags: spring, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

Is there a way I can set some properties to disable DLQ for a queue from the client configuration. I use SpringJMS for configuring my listeners.

I looked at 
http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html but that looks to be on the ActiveMQ Server side. Can I set something like IndividualDeadLetterStrategy for connectionFactory or listenercontainer? In my case, just disabling it from the client for all messages sent from that client would do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is a Broker side configuration and cannot be tweaked from the client end.

Comment: Correct; DLQ is not a function of JMS, it is purely a function of the broker.

Answer (score 2):

ActiveMQ pushes messages into DLQ only if you are throwing an error from Message Listeners. So you can catch the exceptions and avoid pushing to DLQ